# Plotly color not changing Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, plotly.js

I working on a project that needs me to use graph csv file inputs. I've been using plotly and so far it seems to be working very well.

However, when I try to change the color of the graphs (lines and markers) it doesn't work. I am posting excerpts of my code since the color is overall a small portion of the code and I don't want to dump everything here.

```
//There's multiple charts so changing color is important
var r = Math.random() * 256
var g = Math.random() * 256
var b = Math.random() * 256

...
//used these as a vars so I can change things to test easily (multiple time series being used)
 var color='rgb('+r+', '+g+', '+b+')'
var colora='rgba('+r+', '+g+', '+b+', '+'0.14'+')' 

...
//layout of markers
{
                x: time,
                y: time,
                z: data1,
                line: {
                  reversescale: false,

                  //color: "'"+color+"'" 
                  color: "'rgb("+r+', ' +g+', '+ b+")'",

                },
                //mode: 'lines',
                marker: {
                  //color: "'"+color+"'",
                  color: "'rgb("+r+', ' +g+', '+ b+")'",
                  size: 3,
                  line: {
                    //color: "'"+colora+"'",
                    color: "'rgb("+r+', ' +g+', '+ b+")'",
                    width: 0.1
                  },
                  opacity: 0.8
                },
                type: 'scatter3d'
              }
```

Both the attempts just give me the standard black dots. When I tried constants that worked fine (something like color:'rgb(100,100,240)'). Is there something I'm missing here? I've console.logged this thing and it doesn't seem to be an issue with the structure of my vars.

Comment: If you provided a working fiddle, it might be easier to answer your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with my code is that I'm using vars. By switching to consts, I can fix the thing. I didn't catch the color not changing because for some reason the legend was displaying the right colors, but the markers and lines don't accept it.

Answer (score 3):

You have too many quotation marks around your rgb strings. In order to avoid confusion when concatenating strings, you could also use template strings.
See the working fiddle below.

```js
const r = 0;
const g = 255;
const b = 0;
const color = 'rgb(' + r + ',' + g + ',' + b + ')';
const colorTemplate = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;

var trace1 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [10, 15, 13, 17],
  type: 'scatter',
  marker: {
    color: color
  }
};

var trace2 = {
  x: [1, 2, 3, 4],
  y: [16, 5, 11, 9],
  type: 'scatter',
  marker: {
    color: colorTemplate
  }
};

var data = [trace1, trace2];

Plotly.newPlot('myDiv', data);
```

```html
<head>
 <!-- Load plotly.js into the DOM -->
 <script src='https://cdn.plot.ly/plotly-latest.min.js'></script>
</head>

<body>
 <div id='myDiv'><!-- Plotly chart will be drawn inside this DIV --></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I tried your solution. Turns out you can't use vars for the color styling. That's why your thing was working but mine isn't. Where can I learn more about the style you used for declaring colorTemplate?

Comment: If using `const` fixes your issue, you  might have a problem with variable scoping, e.g. your variables `r, g, b` might be overriden someplace else. To read up on template literals, see here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals